# Background music service doesn't turn off

Tags: android, android-studio, service, media-player

I have a service, which plays background music in all of my app's activities.
In every activity I added:

```
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    stopService(new Intent(OpenerPlay.this, MusicDoctorService.class));

}

public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    stopService(new Intent(OpenerPlay.this, MusicDoctorService.class));

}

public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    startService(new Intent(OpenerPlay.this, MusicDoctorService.class));

}

public void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
    startService(new Intent(OpenerPlay.this, MusicDoctorService.class));

}
```

My purpose was to stop or resume service which plays music when I close the app or turn off the screen. But It also stops when I switch to another activity.
Should I change something in my service's code? 
Finally: I would like my service playing music to stop on screen turn off or app closing but not during activities switching.

Service:

```
public class MyService extends Service {


private final String TAG = null;
MediaPlayer player;

public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {

    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.music);
    player.setLooping(true); // Set looping
    player.setVolume(100, 100);




}

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    player.start();
    return 1;
}

public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    // TO DO
}

public IBinder onUnBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TO DO Auto-generated method
    return null;
}


protected void onStop() {
    player.pause();
}

public void onPause() {
    player.pause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    player.stop();
    player.release();
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your Activity's onDestroy Method...

```
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if(isMyServiceRunning(MyService.class))
        {
            stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
        }
    }


private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Here when the Activity is finished you should stop the service..

Also in your service you should release the `mediaplayer`

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (mediaPlayer != null){
        mediaPlayser.stop();
        if (isFinishing()){
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.release();
        }
    }
}
```